# CodeIgniter returns 404 Not Found when installed in a subdirectory on nginx

Tags: codeigniter, nginx

A website - let's call it fru.it - servers a CodeIgniter application under fru.it/blueberry trough nginx and PHP-FPM. 
The main site resides in `/var/www/fru.it/` on the filesystem, while the app is under `/var/www/fru.it_blueberry/blueberry/` (different root than the main site). 
In an attempt to tighten security while CodeIgniter was upgraded to 3.1.0, the app's file structure was changed as per [the CodeIgniter User Manual](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html) to:

```
/var/www/fru.it_blueberry/
├── blueberry
│   ├── application
│   ├── docs
│   ├── public
│   │   ├── index.php
│   └── system
└── sock
```

On development machines the setup works fine with Apache2's default mod_rewrite rules shipped with CI. Accessing fru.it/blueberry/ on the production server, however, displays a CI 404 page.

I'm sure it's a misconfiguration but I can't find the right detail by myself and have been trying with [different setups](https://github.com/allanfreitas/codeigniter-nginx/blob/master/example.com). What do I need to change?

### Application Configuration

The index file is modified to point to absoulte paths of diretories that got moved out of the public root:

```
$system_path = '/var/www/radiostudent.si_klubskimaraton/klubskimaraton/system'
$application_folder = '/var/www/radiostudent.si_klubskimaraton/klubskimaraton/application';
```

This is from `application/config/config.php`:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;
```

In `application/config/routes.php`, a default controller is set to display the homepage at the bare address:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "Welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

### Application Log

```
INFO - 2016-09-02 12:16:19 --> Config Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-09-02 12:16:19 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-09-02 12:16:19 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
INFO - 2016-09-02 12:16:19 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-09-02 12:16:19 --> URI Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-09-02 12:16:19 --> Router Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-09-02 12:16:19 --> Output Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-09-02 12:16:19 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-09-02 12:16:19 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
INFO - 2016-09-02 12:16:19 --> Input Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-09-02 12:16:19 --> Language Class Initialized
ERROR - 2016-09-02 12:16:19 --> 404 Page Not Found: /index
```

### Webserver Configuration

```
location /blueberry {
    error_log /var/www/radiostudent.si_klubskimaraton/main-error.log debug;
    rewrite_log on;
    alias   /var/www/fru.it_blueberry/blueberry/public;
    index   index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

    location ~* \.php$ {
            error_log /var/www/radiostudent.si_klubskimaraton/php-error.log debug;
            rewrite_log on;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass @php-blueberry;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a blank base url.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'www.fru.it/blueberry/';
```

That will help, but might not solve your problem fully as you may have other issues.

In index.php you may also need to set your app paths as well.

```
 $system_path = '/path/to/system/';
 ....
 $application_folder = '/path/to/application';
```

Hope that helps,

Paul.

Comment: Thank you, Paul, but `$system` and `$application_folder` paths are set as you can see in the original question. Setting base URL did not help.

Comment: Oops - sorry, that was an afterthought in fairness.There is a config setting somewhere for the view files folder too, but if CI is finding the error pages, then that probably is not the problem either. Sorry.

Comment: Try a lowercase default controller name, so welcome rather than Welcome.